# SQL insert from table and static data

Tags: sql, insert

I am creating a stored procedure to insert data into a table from another table.  However, all of the data that I want inserted into the new record is not in the other table and at the present time it is not in any table.  I am calling this "static" data.  I have two tables: one called `Resident` and one called `Lease`.  If I have a record in the `Lease` table, I also want an associated record in the `Resident` table for that Lease.

These are the fields that I need to populate in the `Resident` table:

```
    Comp_Name = SMITHJ1234
    Comp_NameLong = SMITH; JOHN
    Comp_Type = Resident
    Comp_Status = Active
    Comp_Source = Import
    Comp_CreatedBy = 1
    Comp_UpdatedBy = 1
```

These are the fields that will come from the `Lease` table:

```
  Lease_primaryresident
  Lease_name
```

So this is what I have right now for stored procedure:

```
 INSERT INTO Resident (Comp_Name,Comp_NameLong)
    SELECT Lease_primaryresident,
       Lease_name
    FROM Lease
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Resident
    WHERE Lease.Lease_primaryresident = Resident.comp_name);
```

How do I get the other items to populate in the `Resident` record (i.e. `comp_type`, `comp_status`, etc.) during this insert?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add literal values to the select, obviously:

```
INSERT INTO Resident (Comp_Name,Comp_NameLong, Comp_Type, Comp_Status)
SELECT 
   Lease_primaryresident,
   Lease_name,
   'Resident',
   'Active'
FROM Lease
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Resident
WHERE Lease.Lease_primaryresident = Resident.comp_name);
```